# Why is my protected method not returning what I setup in mock

Tags: c#, moq

Why is my protected method not returning what I setup in mock? When running unit test the protected method is returning 99 but I expected 1 since I set it up like that in the mock.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMockTarget>();
    mock.SetupGet(x => x.PropertyToMock).Returns("FixedValue");

    mock.Protected()
        .Setup<int>("MyProtectedGetIntMethod")
        .Returns(1);

    var sut = new ClassToTest();

    var actualValue = sut.GetPrefixedValue(mock.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual("Prefixed:FixedValue1", actualValue);
}
```

Class under test

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    public string GetPrefixedValue(IMockTarget provider)
    {
        var x = MyProtectedGetIntMethod();
        return $"Prefixed:{provider.PropertyToMock}{x}";
    }

    protected int MyProtectedGetIntMethod() { return 99; }
}

public interface IMockTarget
{
    string PropertyToMock { get; }
    protected int MyProtectedGetIntMethod();
}
```

Comment: You're not mocking `ClassToTest`, which is where the protected method is defined. You're not calling your `IMockTarget` implementation of `MyProtectedGetIntMethod`. You should call `provider.MyProtectedGetIntMethod()`. This is also a wonderful case for using a debugger, because this would have jumped out at you immediately when you stepped through line-by-line.

Comment: Also: This is clearly a contrived example, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it, because you're not using any sort of inheritance that would necessitate a `protected` method.

Comment: i'm just trying to understand how to use moq in advanced scenarios

Comment: Moq works by either subclassing a class or implementing an interface. Therefore, when mocking a class, it can only mock virtual methods, since it's really overriding them.

Comment: is there a recommended resource to get up to speed quickly with moq

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the behaviour of `ClassToTest.MyProtectedGetIntMethod`, you should mock the `ClassToTest` class:

```
var mock2 = new Mock<ClassToTest>();
mock2.Protected()
     .Setup<int>("MyProtectedGetIntMethod")
     .Returns(1);

var actualValue = mock2.Object.GetPrefixedValue(mock.Object);
```

The `MyProtectedGetIntMethod` method also needs to be virtual for the mocking framework to work.

```
protected virtual int MyProtectedGetIntMethod() { return 99; }
```

Comment: I feel like this is a misleading answer because you shouldn't mock the thing you're testing. The problem is that the mocked method isn't being called in the first place.

Comment: It's protected. How can you call it in another class?

Comment: Exactly. The entire starting premise of the question is flawed. This person needs to understand how to use protected methods *and* how to test them. Telling them to mock the class under test is pointing them down the wrong path.